# rails ruby view code for hiding erb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, erb

I have this in my view code:

```
<h2>What Others Are Saying...</h2>

<% @comments.each do |comment| %>
<ul>
    <li><%= comment.email %></li>
    <li><%= comment.body %></li>
</ul>
<% end %>

<hr>
<%= render "comments/comment_form" %>
```

controller code:

```
  before_filter :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]

  def index
    @posts = Post.all
  end

  def show
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    @comment = @post.comments.build
    @comments = @post.comments
  end
```

When there are no comments, I still see the ul > li in my DOM, is there a way to not render this until soemone has actually posted a message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `@comments` variable is not empty. When database return zero comments, you still have a new comment instance in `@comments` array. That is the reason your HTML code is being rendered while you see no comments. You can use the following code

```
<% @comments.each do |comment| %>
  <% if comment.id? %>
    <ul>
      <li><%= comment.email %></li>
      <li><%= comment.body %></li>
    </ul>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

**UPDATE**

```
@comment = @post.comments.build
# When you do @post.comments after building in the above line,
# your @comments will have the built comment as well.
@comments = @post.comments
```

Comment: I faced this scenario myself once. This was first thought crossing my mind after reading your question :)

Answer (score 1):

I originally misunderstood your question and thought you wanted a single `<ul></ul>` wrapping all comments, and to avoid an empty `<ul></ul>` when there were no comments.  In that case a simple `if` block would have sufficed:

```
<h2>What Others Are Saying...</h2>

<% if ! @comments.empty? %>
    <ul>
    <% @comments.each do |comment| %>
         <li><%= comment.email %></li>
         <li><%= comment.body %></li>
    <% end %>
    </ul>
<% end %>
```

But as others have noted, the issue is actually due to your use of `@post.comments.build` prior to assigning to `@comments`.  I'm not sure why you do that `build`, but if you did it *after* assigning to `@comments` then it would probably go away.

Comment: You can use `unless` instead of `if !` for this case as well!

Answer (score 1):

If @comments is an empty array, nothing in the loop should render.
Check if @comments is really empty

```
<%= @comments.size %>
```

controller should not call build

```
  def show
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    @comments = @post.comments
  end
```

Comment: it says that it is 1, but all the inspect values say nil.

Comment: how do you set @comments variable?

Comment: No, he doesn't need to remove build. It's there because he'll have to render the new comment form.

Answer (score 0):

Strange, if the `@comments` instance variable is empty nothing inside the `each` block should be rendered.

If `@comments` is referenced through another model (`@blog.comments` or something) are you sure you're not building a "blank" comment in the controller (e.g. `@blog.comments.build`) for the comment_form?

If you could show us the controller action and maybe the rest of the view it might become clear.

To debug you could also place this line before the `each` block:

```
<%= @comments.inspect %>
```

That should show you whether the `@comments` variable is truly empty.

Comment: It says everything is nil! I think Kulbir is on the to right idea.

Comment: It shouldn't say everything is nil, if it's rendering something. But I agree Kulbir's answer is correct.